# How did 優しさ derived from 優しい? The rule is？

Tags: i-adjectives, suffixes, nominalization

How did 優しさ derived from 優しい? The rule is？

Comment: Related (or possible duplicate?): https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/6665/9831

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/42512/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1429/9831

Answer (score 2):

> 優し**さ**

The suffix (接尾辞)「さ」, attached to the stem (語幹) of i-adjectives and na-adjectives, turns them into the noun form, like this:

> i-adjective おおきい "big" - stem おおき + suffix さ → おおきさ "size"
>   na-adjective にぎやかな "lively" - stem にぎやか + suffix さ → にぎやかさ "liveliness"

A few more examples:

> i-adjectives:
>   かわいい "cute" → かわいさ "cuteness"
>   [長]{なが}い "long" → 長さ "length"
>   [明]{あか}るい "bright" → 明るさ "brightness"
>
> na-adjectives:
>   きれいな "clean" → きれいさ "cleanness"
>   [華]{はな}やかな "brilliant" → 華やかさ "brilliance"
>   [便利]{べんり}な "convenient" → 便利さ "convenience"

Comment: Got it clearly now. Thx a lot.